# Why `dataclasses.make_dataclass` does not cast `bytes` to `bool`

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I have the following question. I've tried to create `dataclass` from SQL query result, using `make_dataclass` function. Let's assume that my record looks so:

```
import dataclasses

record = {
    'name': 'asdasd',
    'age': None,
    'is_active': bytes(1),
    'is_admin': bytes(0),
    'amount': 1
}


def make_field(k, v):
    t = type(v)
    if isinstance(v, bytes):
        t = bool
    return k, t


Record = dataclasses.make_dataclass('Record', [make_field(k, v) for k, v in record.items()])
```

Then if value is a bytes, I wanna have bool instead. But result looks following:

`Record(name='asdasd', age=None, is_active=b'\x00', is_admin=b'', amount=1)`

I have 2 questions:

1. Why is it continues to be bytes? Because bool is also bytes?
2. Is there a better way to have a bool instead `r.is_active = bool(r.is_active)`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

They're still bytes because you said that the type for the field is `bool`, but that doesn't mean that it will be cast to that type. It's perfectly legal to give the wrong type to a dataclass or a plain variable, and the data won't be converted to the annotated type automatically:

```
var: int = "Wrong type"  # Causes a warning, not an error
print(var, type(var))  # Prints "Wrong type <class 'str'>"
```

Type hints are purely for static-type checking reasons, and aren't actually enforced unless you modify your IDE settings to have type-hinting warnings treated as actual errors. Even if you did have them treated as errors, it wouldn't cast the data for you, and likely wouldn't even be able to catch the mistake in this exact case anyways.

---

As for how to deal with it, you're going to need to manually handle this. You could create a custom "constructor" that does the conversion. Regardless of how you do it though, you're going to have to write something along the lines of `r.is_active = bool(r.is_active)` somewhere.